# Enabling OpenMPI support when compiling John the Ripper 1.8.0

Tags: makefile, compilation

I just made a VPN network between my VPS's and wanted them to run some John the Ripper tasks. I followed [this](http://louwrentius.com/parallel-distributed-password-cracking-with-john-the-ripper-and-mpi.html) manual, but since 1.8.0 version John the Ripper's Makefile does not have the following lines, which it refers to:

```
 CC = mpicc -DHAVE_MPI -DJOHN_MPI_BARRIER -DJOHN_MPI_ABORT`
 MPIOBJ = john-mpi.o
```

There's a legacy Makefile, which has the

```
 CC = mpicc -DHAVE_MPI
```

part, but, when I tried to compile with this, I see a lot of errors. I assume this legacy Makefile is not longer supported.

**How can I enable OpenMPI support when compiling John the Ripper?**

In case it matters, I am running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use that Makefile.
Do this:

```
./configure --enable-mpi
```

See if the report gave yes for OpenMPI
Then:

```
make -s
```